# Can we use @Environment to access a properties at two different places

Tags: spring

I 'm trying to access the properties file other than a place where all the application's configuration resides(Datasource,SessionFactory,TransactionManager), hence I'm trying to use `@Environment` twice in my application.

I'm trying to load a properties file to implement a email notification functionality to access the properties file content using env by auto wiring.  But I'm failing while reading the property file using `env.getProperty("email.smtp.host")`); Getting `null` in the place of property value when executing the app.

Actually, I'm trying to use two Configuration file, is this what blocks me to autowire `Environment` property ? I tried to replace with `@Component` and adding email package to componentscan list as well.  I'm thinking that, is `Environement` property applicable only to `@Configuration` file ? Can someone help me to debug the issue please or what I'm missing here to initiate the `Environment` ?

1. I tried to resolve this by implementing `EnvironmentAware` interface as below to get the property value using `load()` but that still didn't help me.
2. Tried to use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as below.

```java
@Bean

public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}


    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:email.properties")
public class PropertiesUtil implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Autowired
     private Environment environment;

     public void sendPlainTextEmail(String mailMessage) throws AddressException, MessagingException{
     try {
        // Configure SMTP
            Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host",this.env.getProperty("email.smtp.host"));

properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
      }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public String load(String propertyName)
    {
        return environment.getRequiredProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Expecting to read the email property but getting only Null and no other information to debug.

Comment: Let me guess you are doing `new PropertiesUitl` in your code, instead of auto wiring it?

Comment: Thanks Deinum for helping me. I'm not trying to autowire PropertyUtil yet. Perhaps, my understanding about your clarification is less ? Could be brief some more please ?

Comment: If you don't autowire you don't get a spring managed instance and thus nothign will be autowired.